# should I use utf-8 or utf-16 or utf-32 for my multilingual cms?

Tags: utf

Besides the difference in how characters are stored, are there any special characters in any language utf-32 can display and utf-8 cannot?

Comment: What language (and therefore range of characters) will be dominant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All UTF encodings can represent the [same range of code points](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) (0 to 0x10FFFF). So, the same characters can be encoded by any of them.

Whether they can be "displayed" is an entirely different question. That's nothing to do with the encoding, and a function of the font family used. I am not sure that any font has glyphs for every single Unicode code point. But I assume you meant "represented".

They do vary in how many bytes they'll need to represent a given string. UTF-8 is almost always the shortest for non-Asian languages. For those, UTF-16 might win (I haven't really "benchmarked".) I can't imagine a realistic case where UTF-32 would be optimal.

Answer (score 1):

#### *Is there any character one of them can't represent?*

#### In theory: No.

All of those formats can represent all Unicode code points.

#### In practice: Depends.

The Windows API uses UCS-2 (which is pretty much the first UTF-16 chunk) and doesn't always handle surrogates correctly. So you might want to use UTF-16 to have your program act as "normal" as possible compared to other programs, instead of truncating high-ranging UTF-32 code points manually.

#### *Anything else?*

#### Yes: Use UTF-8!

It's endian-less, so you it avoids byte-order issues, which are a pain in the rear.
Of course, if you're on Windows then you need to convert to UTF-16 before using them.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 all can be used to represent all Unicode datapoints. So no, there are no special characters that can be represented in UTF-32 and not in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

1) UTF-8 can be backward compatible with ASCII for regular english characters, this can be an advantage when your client just have english characters.

2) UTF-8 is good in saving network bandwidth if you have ASCII characters more than non-English characters.

3) UTF-16 would be good if you have more non-English characters in terms of saving Storage space.

I suggest to use UTF-8 based on #1 above.